# If I have a class A with a field foo that is a Dictionary, how can I make A implement IDictionary quickly using foo as dataset?

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface

I have the following code :

```
public class A
{
    Dictionary<T1,T2> foo
    var otherVariable;
    // some other irrelevant code
}
```

I want `A` to implement `IDictionary<T1,T2>` or be able to use `A` as a `Dictionary<T1,T2>` easily.

So far I see two obvious solutions :

1. Implement explicitly with code such as

   `public int Count
   {
       get { return foo.Count();}
   }`
2. Add an implicit conversion of `A` to `Dictionary<T1,T2>`, which is more or less enough for my use...for now.

I don't like 2 because I want `A` to do a little more than `foo`.

I can obviously do 1 (in fact I did it) but it can be a bit lengthy to implement all the methods of `IDictionary<T1,T2>`.

Is there a third way ?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but why not expose the field as a public property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution, an automated way to do what I want with Visual Studio 2015.

When I add the interface `IInterface` to class `A` with a field member `foo` that already implements it, it offers me the option to implement `IInterface` through `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a third way?

No, there is no third way: if you want instances of `A` to be usable as if they were an `IDictionary<T1,T2>`, and you do not wish to derive your class from `Dictionary<T1,T2>`, then the two ways that you have listed are what you have to work with.

> [I want to] be able to use `A` as a `Dictionary<T1,T2>` easily.

Deriving from the dictionary makes sense only when your class `A` is indeed a dictionary. If, on the other hand, it only has a dictionary, without being a dictionary, you may want to use either the conversion operator, or even an appropriately named property for the conversion:

```
public IDictionary<T1,T2> AsDictionary => foo; // C# 6 syntax
```

or

```
public IDictionary<T1,T2> AsDictionary { get { return foo; } } // Legacy C# syntax
```